# How to create custom link for category?

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I have to create category in Magento backend, it display to front end, can it possible if category name is Ex. like Football, and when i click it football category, it redirect to another sites link?

Ex. Category 1 Is Football -> Site 1 Name Like Ex. *www.football.com* and when click Football category its Redirect It Site 2 Like Ex. *www.hockey.com*

Pls Help And Suggest Some Ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest possible way to do is:

**Admin Level:** In the category(Football) description you can add some script:

```
<script>window.location.href = "http://www.football.com";</script>
```

**Code Level (Dirty way):** You need to override core file: `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php`

There inside function `_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml` find below code

```
$html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
$html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
$html[] = '</a>';
```

& then put condition to identify category the compose the URL & replace with `$this->getCategoryUrl($category)`as per your requirement.

Comment: its working but when click any category first its go to current category then redirect another category.

Comment: can have a other ways?

Comment: Other way is code level changes. See my updated answer. With Admin changes it will do that way only.

Comment: Please do up vote & mark as accepted, if this helped. So this will help for the  people also, have same requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you want to do this, but you can achieve by `.htaccess`

use 301 redirect rule for that

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  #301 redirect
  redirect 301 oldURL NEWURL
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create custom Url Rewrites from Magento Admin panel.

Magento admin > Catalog > URL Rewrite Management >

Search for current category request path and delete it

Now you will able to create new url rewrite for that particular category.

```
ID Path : unique id path 
Request Path : football.html 
Target Path    :www.hockey.com 
Redirect : 301
```